# How to inherit from QWidget in PyQt?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qwidget

Maigcally I can't inherit from QWidget using PyQt 4:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.resize(200, 200)
    widget1 = MyWidget(window)
    widget1.resize(100, 100)
    widget1.setStyleSheet("background-color:#FFFFFF")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It doesn't work. I just can't see the widget. But, using QLabel instead of QWidget works.

Thanks.

**Solution**

Reimplement paintEvent:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        o = QStyleOption()
        o.initFrom(self)
        p = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, o, p, self)
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? Is there an error? Does the window not appear? You need to be a little more descriptive.

Comment: The widget doesn't appear inside the window.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the difference? Based on your code, although you declare a parent of the DnDWidget, you don't actually place it inside the window, so I'd expect it wouldn't show up.

Comment: This is the preview of the code above: [link](http://i.imgur.com/MwdoNQ5.png). And this is the preview if I inherit from QLabel: [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZDPiDTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subclassing correctly. The "problem" is just that the QWidget has the same background colour as the main window (your call to setStyleSheet is not working).

As proof, run this code from a terminal:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel

class MyWidget(QWidget):
     def enterEvent(self, evt):
        print 'a'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.resize(200, 200)
    widget1 = MyWidget(window)
    widget1.resize(100, 100)
    widget1.setStyleSheet("background-color:#FFFFFF")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When you move your mouse into the first 100,100 pixel square, you will see the letter 'a' being printed in the terminal

Comment: When using this code, changing the stylesheet to any color deosnt work

Comment: Any idea why the call to setStyleSheet is not working? I'm running into the same issue and I assumed that MyWidget should behave exactly like QWidget when it inherits from QWidget and doesn't override any methods.